# Text Encodings for large text dataset

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, memory, encoding

I am having trouble encoding large amounts oftextual data to numbers

**Problem** : memory issues during encoding

**Things I tried** :

```py
# Using traditional Python
TITLE_list = ' '.join(df["TITLE"].dropna()).split(" ")
```

```py
# Bag of words
bog = pd.Series([y for x in df.iloc[: , :4].dropna().values.flatten() for y in x.split()]).value_counts()
```

I also tried using other encoders but all result in the same memory error

This is the memory size of my server: (Output of !free --mega) (note this is in megabytes)

```sh
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          13302         498       12097           1         707       12545
Swap:             0           0           0
```

**Data example**:

```sh
    TITLE         DESCRIPTION                  BULLET_POINTS    BRAND    
0   Pete The Cat, Pete the Cat is the coolest, [Pete the Cat ]  MeMakers
```

**Help needed** : Solution to encode large amounts of text data to respective numbers such that I can feed them to a neural network architecture

Answer (score 0):

You should try an another approch...
Instead of trying to create a list, you can try to manage an "iterator object".
By doing this, python will keep in memory only the currently used iteration.
(saving a lot of memory)

Just an example:

```
l1=[1,2,3,4,5]
l2=iter(l1)
print (l2) #Output:<list_iterator object at 0x0164E658>

#Iterating through iterable(l1) using for loop.
    for i in l1:
        print (i,end=" ") #Output:1 2 3 4 5
    
    
#Iterating through iterator(l2) using for loop.
    for i in l2:
        print (i,end=" ") #Output:1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: The loop is not the problem, the list I am creating in the process is taking more memory then the server can handle and is crashing the server

Answer (score 0):

I had to use batching in the end to make this work :
Here is a code snippet of the working code that I used :

```py
n = 16
for i in tqdm.tqdm(range(0, int(df.shape[0]), n)):
        df["TITLE"].iloc[i:i + n] = df["TITLE"].iloc[i:i + n].apply(lambda x: [item for item in x.split() if item not in stop]  if type(x) == str else x)
```